# Update directory full of rpms

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, repository

I've got a directory with about 400 rpms. What can I do to make yum/rpm fetch the last version from the system repository with all its dependencies and replace the old rpm? I'm using CentOS 6.4.

Comment: you mean refresh your local directory with newer versions coming from official repositories ?

Comment: Exactly, the latest available for this version.

Answer (score 0):

you can add that directory as a repository. If the path to your rpm-dir is /path/to/rpm-dir:

first convert that directory into a repository:

```
cd /path/to/rpm-dir
createrepo .
```

now add this new repository:

```
echo "[my-rpm-dir]
name=my directory Repository
baseurl=file:///path/to/rpm-dir
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0" > /etc/yum.repos.d/my-rpm-dir.repo
```

now you can run updates as usual:

```
yum update
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I might be doing something wrong. I tried exactly like you told, but yum installs the updates to the system, not the repo-directory. Any idea what I'm screwing up?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do then? you are trying to extract rpms from your system to inject them into the directory? That is not possible...

Comment: the only thing you could do then would be to fetch the rpms from the repositories and put them in the directory...

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @rage that is not an answer, so please delete that. All that is happening is that none of the rpms in your repository is an update for any of the rpms installed on your system.

Comment: Then I might be unclear with my question. An example: [root@localhost new-repo]# yum list httpd --showduplicates
...
Installed Packages
httpd.x86_64    .2.15-60.el6.centos.6  @updates

Available Packages
httpd.x86_64  2.2.15-26.el6.centos     NewRepo

httpd.x86_64  2.2.15-60.el6.centos.6   updates   There is Version 60 available, my local repo only got version -26 - how can I update the local update to get version -60 ?

Comment: As I said above, once installed the rpm packages are not anymore as such on you system and you cannot recover them. You have to get them where they came from (the repositories).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to turn your directory to a local repository, and then update it. Take a look at this post for example:
http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/network-services/creating-a-yum-repository-server-for-red-hat-and-centos/